# _recalloc in UNIX not found

Tags: linux, unix, malloc, realloc

Cant find _recalloc function in UNIX (not defined). Using headers:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <malloc.h>
```

Where is it? Or how to implement?

**UPDATE.**
There is no "recalloc" string in my "//usr/include/malloc.h" file. I wrote another function like this:

```
inline void* _recalloc(void* _Memory, _In_ size_t _Count, _In_ size_t _Size)
{
    return memset(_Memory + _Count, 0, sizeof(_Memory) * (_Size - _Count));
}
```

Is it correct?

Comment: Seems like a strange function. Why not just `free` and then `calloc` if you're going to zero it anyway ? `realloc` just copies stuff which you then zero out.

Comment: I'm not sure about internal implementation of _recalloc, so i'm asking for help.

Comment: Note : you cant add to void pointers. (and your function is terribly wrong, since it (re)allocates nothing, sizeof _memory is wrong and substracting `(_size - _count)` smells bad, too )

Comment: @wildplasser, ok then how to implement it?

Comment: Short answer: you can't. You would need to know the old size, which you don't. The real realloc() knows the old size because it can inspect the *internal* (hidden) contents of the memory blocks (which are maintained by malloc/free/calloc/realloc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Quoted](http://unix.derkeiler.com/Newsgroups/comp.unix.programmer/2004-08/0359.html)::

manpages will tell you where a function's definition comes from (ANSI C, POSIX, SysV, BSD, etc).

The fact that `malloc()`, `calloc()`, `realloc()`, and `free()` are defined in `<stdlib.h>` while `_recalloc()` is defined in `<malloc.h>` is a clue that the latter is an [IRIX-specific feature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IRIX).